# Count function return 0 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, eager-loading

I want to show count of product for company using `count` function but it return `0` why? 
And what is the true syntax for relation?
and how I can get the sql query from function of model?

**Agent_Company.php**

```
class Agent_Company extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table='agent_companies';
    protected $primaryKey='id';
    protected $fillable=['companyName','description','id_image'];

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product','id','id_company');
    }
    public function image(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Image','id_image');
    }
}
```

**Product.php**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table='products';
    protected $primaryKey='id';
    protected $fillable=[
            'product','video','id_company','id_image',
    ];
    public function Image(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Image');
    }
    public function Agent_Company(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Agent_Company','id_company','id');
    }
}
```

there is the view:

```
<div class="container">
    {{$agent_Company->links()}}
    <div class="row" id="company">
        @foreach($agent_Company as $item)
            <div class="card col-md-4" style="width: 300px; max-height: 500px;">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h2>{{$item->companyName}}</h2>
                </div>
                <img src="{{'agent_Companye_Images/'.$item->image->image}}" class="card-img-top"
                     alt="{{$item->image->alt}}" style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
                <div class="card-body" style="overflow:auto">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Product:{{DD($item->Products->count())}}</h5>
                    <span class="card-title">
                        <a href="" class=" btn btn-primary"> Go to Company</a>
                        {{$item->description}}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're not eager loading your `products` relation, then the count will be `0`, because you're counting the number of *loaded* product relations, not the number of product relations (stored in the database).

Comment: so..?
what i should to change ?
and thx

Comment: In your controller, eager load your products relation. E.g:`AgentCompany::with('products')->findOrFail(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You have switched the parameters in the `products` relation in model `Agent_Company`. The correct would be:

```php
public function products(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Product','id_company','id');
}
```

Also worthy of note:
I agree with @fubar that [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) using `with()` is in almost all cases desired. That said, even when you don't eager load, you can still get the relation as a property. That is called [lazy loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties).

Answer (score 0):

@Augusto Moura is correct, you have switched foreign key and local key. You should fix that first.

To answer to your issue, there is no need to eager load Products because you only need a count. You will run into run time problems (memory) when working with big amounts of data.

Thus in your model you should declare

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product','id_company');
}
```

As function names are case sensitive, count the products as `$item->products()->count()`. If you ask for `$item->products->count()` laravel will still load all products in memory and count them from there. Make use of the ORM model() relationship to avoid that.

On database level, the difference is in the SQL request. $item->products->count() will be something like `SELECT * from products WHERE ...` where laravel counts the amount of objects, compared to `SELECT count() as products_count from products WHERE ...`

You could actually eager load only counted products by adding `->withCount('products')` and in Blade `{{ $item->products_count }}`